# Using Linux virtual ethernet interfaces (veth) to test a custom TCP stack

Tags: linux, sockets, curl, tcp, network-programming

If have set up a pair of virtual ethernet devices veth0 and veth1:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1

# Bring the interfaces up
sudo ifconfig veth0 up
sudo ifconfig veth1 up

sudo ifconfig veth0 1.1.1.1
sudo ifconfig veth1 1.1.1.2
```

Inside my application I connect to `veth0` using a raw socket. Incoming packets are forwarded to my own TCP/IP stack implementation. Replies from the stack are sent back to the socket.

I also have a simple HTTP server running on my stack. I try to connect to it using the `curl`:

```
sudo curl -vvv --interface veth1 1.1.1.1/1/2/10000
*   Trying 1.1.1.1...
* Local Interface veth1 is ip 1.1.1.2 using address family 2
* Local port: 0
```

Now my custom stack receives the `SYN`, enters the `SYN-RECEIVED` state and replies a with a `SYN-ACK`. This is sent down the stack back to the raw socket.

However, it seems that curl is not receiving the `SYN-ACK` because it keeps retransmitting the original `SYN`.

According to tcpdump the SYN-ACK does seem to arrive on 1.1.1.2:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i veth1  -vv
tcpdump: listening on veth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:43:41.680087 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59135, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    1.1.1.2.41847 > 1.1.1.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x0433 (incorrect -> 0x38a4), seq 446675468, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1266013534 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:43:41.680345 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30106, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.1.1.1.http > 1.1.1.2.41847: Flags [S.], cksum 0x0bbe (correct), seq 697874744, ack 446675469, win 65535, options [mss 1460,wscale 5,nop,sackOK,nop,nop], length 0
02:43:42.690344 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59136, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    1.1.1.2.41847 > 1.1.1.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x0433 (incorrect -> 0x34b2), seq 446675468, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1266014544 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:43:44.706343 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59137, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    1.1.1.2.41847 > 1.1.1.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x0433 (incorrect -> 0x2cd2), seq 446675468, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1266016560 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:43:46.850382 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 1.1.1.1 tell 1.1.1.2, length 28
02:43:46.850579 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 1.1.1.1 is-at 92:c6:e5:d6:03:2f (oui Unknown), length 46
02:43:47.680487 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30107, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.1.1.1.http > 1.1.1.2.41847: Flags [S.], cksum 0x0bbe (correct), seq 697874744, ack 446675469, win 65535, options [mss 1460,wscale 5,nop,sackOK,nop,nop], length 0
02:43:48.898343 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59138, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    1.1.1.2.41847 > 1.1.1.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x0433 (incorrect -> 0x1c72), seq 446675468, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1266020752 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:43:57.090346 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59139, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    1.1.1.2.41847 > 1.1.1.1.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x0433 (incorrect -> 0xfc71), seq 446675468, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1266028944 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:43:59.680648 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30108, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.1.1.1.http > 1.1.1.2.41847: Flags [S.], cksum 0x0bbe (correct), seq 697874744, ack 446675469, win 65535, options [mss 1460,wscale 5,nop,sackOK,nop,nop], length 0
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

[Wireshark screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD0VS.png)

Does anyone know why my `SYN-ACK` doesn't reach the other side of the TCP connection?

Comment: This might be better suited for [SF]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that veth interfaces are using checksum offload by default so the forwarded packets had a bad checksum and were ignored by the kernel. Running 'ethtool --offload IF_NAME rx off tx off' on veth interfaces (the sender and receiver), you may fix it.